# Buddypress groups + P2 integration

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

There are two things I love that I wish would work together a little more nicely.

I am helping some students create a site that allows them to share statuses and comments. Buddypress seemed like an awesome tool for this because the students had some pretty logical groups.

However, P2 provides most of the rest that they want out of the box, namely the ability to quickly share statuses, links and reply to each other. Combined with the ability for Buddypress to allow users to follow users and like statuses, this is a pretty good deal.

We thought it would be perfect if we could click a group and then essentially get the ability to have this same interface that P2 provides but constrained to the group.

So far, we have not been able to achieve this. When we click on a group in Buddypress the "speed of light" aspect of P2 is now gone and we get the typical Buddypress group sharing interface.

Is there a way to enable P2 to work with the groups feature?

Answer (score 1):

Try https://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-groupblog/

It's a fairly old plugin but it seems to have been updated recently, and it should do what you want it to do (embed a blog inside a BuddyPress group).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm checking it out. It's definitely a great lead!